# How to total up all drop down menu

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I need help I'm new to this but I have 3 dropdown menus how would count them and total them all up to prompt the user if the total of the dropdowns is more then 10 in total:

I have added the code I'm using below:

```html
<table align="center" width="360" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="270" align="right">N1:</td>
    <td width="270" align="right">
      <select name="N1" id="N1">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td width="270" align="right">N2:</td>
    <td width="270" align="right">
      <select name="N2" id="N2">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <td width="370" align="right">N3:</td>
  <td width="270" align="right">
    <select name="N3" id="N3">
      <option value="0">0</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>

  </td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Isn't clear enough..

Comment: _"total them all up"_ - what do you mean?

Comment: btw: interpunctuation is your friend! use it!

Comment: but to answer: write a js-function that gets called every time a select gets changed ('onchange'), then just calculate the sum of all 3.

Comment: I want take the user input on the drop down menu and total up there selection

Comment: ok got it . and already wrote an answer above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attach the change event to all the three select's, then on change loop through the select's you've and calculate the total sum of the selected value, like :

```
$('select').each(function() {
    total += Number($(this).val());
});
```

Code:

```js
$('select').on('change', function() {
  var total = 0;

  $('select').each(function() {
    total += Number($(this).val());
  });
  console.log(total);
  if (total > 10) {
    console.log('Alert user');
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table align="center" width="360" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="270" align="right">N1:</td>
    <td width="270" align="right">
      <select name="N1" id="N1">
      <option value="0">0</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
     </select>
    </td>
    <td width="270" align="right">N2:</td>
    <td width="270" align="right">
      <select name="N2" id="N2">
      <option value="0">0</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
     </select>
    </td>
    <td width="370" align="right">N3:</td>
    <td width="270" align="right">
      <select name="N3" id="N3">
      <option value="0">0</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```